# how can i hide the keypad from iphone simulator after its use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

how can i hide the keypad from iphone simulator after its use ? 
in my app Ist textfield is for name , another one is for password and one button i want to
hide the keypad whenever i clicked on button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in button action routine write [yourTextField resignFirstResponder]. it will hide your keyboard.

Jim.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 method to do it...

1> Implement

```
- (IBAction) doneButtonOnKeyboardPressed: (id)sender
{

}
```

Method on Textfield 's Did End On Exit Event

OR

In Textfield implement this delegate method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
[txtName resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If we want to close keyboard of simulator when mouse click outside of UITextView (with name "myTextView"), we can use:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.myTextView.resignFirstResponder;
    // or [myTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```